# Fetching session state without sending HTTP request from front end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-session

Setup ASP.NET Core with Reactjs + Redux + Saga. It needs to notify the user when asp.net core session is expired. But the problem is by sending GET requests to check the session status we extend the session which means the session will not ever be over unless the tab in the browser will be closed(then GET requests won't be sent). This is the session setup `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 * 60);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });
```

And then we send every 5 minute request from client to get identity:

```
function* checkSessionIsValid() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(axios.get, 'api/Customer/FetchIdentity');

            if (!response.data) {
                return yield put({
                    type: types.SESSION_EXPIRED,
                });

            yield delay(300000);
            return yield put({ type: types.CHECK_SESSION_IS_VALID });
        }
        return;
    } catch (error) {
        return;
    }
}
```

And the backend endpoint(_context is `IHttpContextAccessor`):

```
        [HttpGet("FetchIdentity")]
        public LoginInfo GetIdentity()
        {
            if (SessionExtension.GetString(_context.Session, "_emailLogin") != null)
            {
                return new LoginInfo()
                {
                    LoggedInWith = "email",
                    LoggedIn = true,
                    Identity = ""
                };
            }

            return null;
        }
```

So we get session info from `SessionExtension`. But probably there is some way of getting it without connecting to the back end?

Comment: When you are calling `GetIdentity`, are any cookies being set (check the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools)?

Comment: @mjwills I think cookies being updated with new time stamp each time you send a request or access `SessionExtension` class, but they are encrypted and you cannot read from it

Comment: Can you show us the details of the cookie from Chrome Developer Tools - including when they expire?

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking isn't possible, and frankly doesn't make sense when you understand how sessions work. A session only exists in the context of a request. HTTP is a stateless protocol. Sessions essentially fake state by having the server and client pass around a "session id". When a server wants to establish a "session" with a client, it issues a session id to the client, usually via the `Set-Cookie` response header. The client then, will pass back this id on each subsequent request, usually via the `Cookie` request header. When the server receives this id, it looks up the corresponding session from the store, and then has access to whatever state was previously in play.

The point is that without a request *first*, the server doesn't know or care about what's going on with a particular session. The expiration part happens when the server next tries to look up the session. If it's been too long (the session expiration has passed), then it destroys the previous session and creates a new one. It doesn't actively monitor sessions to do anything at a particular time. And, since as you noted, sessions are sliding, each request within the expiration timeframe resets that timeframe. As a result, a session never expires as long as the client is actively using it.

Long and short, the only way to know the state of the session is to make a request with a session id, in order to prompt the server to attempt to restore that session. The best you can do if you want to track session expiration client-side is to set a timer client-side based on the known timeout. You then need to reset said time, with every further request.

```
 var sessionTimeout = setTimeout(doSomething, 20 * 60 * 1000); // 20 minutes
```

Then, in your AJAX callbacks:

```
 clearTimeout(sessionTimeout);
 sessionTimeout = setTimeout(doSomething, 20 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I guess there could be only 2 possible workarounds, first is send timestamp in the header for instance and set the timer and second is to use something like SignalR. Since I want to be in full sync with backend session, I don't want to hardcode timers in front end

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the SessionState attribute can be utilized.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp

**EDIT: Realized that you're using .NET Core, not sure if the SessionState attribute or anything similar exist as of today.**